# restclient with ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest

Here i am trying to pass one ID with the url, but that ID didn't append with URL...

```
def retrieve
    url =  "http://localhost:3000/branches/"
    resource = RestClient::Resource.new url+$param["id"]
    puts resource
end
```

giving ID via commend line that is

```
ruby newrest.rb  id="22"
```

I have got the error like this

```
`+': can't convert nil into String (TypeError)
```

But  all this working with mozilla rest client. How to rectify this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the command line parameters in the global ARGV array.

If `ruby newrest.rb 22` will do then just

```
id = ARGV[0]
response = RestClient.get "http://localhost:3000/branches/#{id}"
puts response.body
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
RestClient.get 'http://localhost:3000/branches', {:params => {:id => 50, 'name' => 'value'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples from the documentation:

```
private_resource = RestClient::Resource.new 'https://example.com/private/resource', 'user', 'pass'

RestClient.post 'http://example.com/resource', :param1 => 'one', :nested => { :param2 => 'two' }
```

Just experiment with comma-separated parameters or with hashes so see what your URL gives you.

Comment: just i need to append the value, which passing through command line. that i mean if i give the id via command line,
"http://localhost:3000/branches/22" here the 22 is the id value, which i am passing with the command line
ruby newrest.rb id="22". So how to get that value and append with that url

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view line `puts resource` seems strange,
but when we leave it as it is
I'd suggest

```
def retrieve
    url =  "http://localhost:3000/branches/"
    resource = RestClient::Resource.new url
    res_with_param = resource[$param["id"]]
    puts res_with_param
end
```

I haven't tried so there may be a syntax mistakes.
I'm really newcomer in ruby.
But idea is good I hope.

Greetings,
KAcper